# What wrong with my stored Procedure,it ends without executing the main logic

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have exported different stored procedures into MySql from Oracle but there is something wrong with this stored procedure, it ends without executing.

I have tried moving data dumps from the tables but it's still not working

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%'
PROCEDURE MOB_INSURANCE.PRC_INITIATE_INSURANCE_PAYMENT(
                             in PARAM_BEN_CNIC varchar(4000),
                             in PARAM_INITIATOR_MSISDN varchar(4000),
                             in PARAM_BENEFICIARY_MSISDN varchar(4000),
                             in PARAM_INITIATOR_CNIC varchar(4000),
                             out PARAM_TID varchar(4000),
                             in PARAM_FEE double,
                             in PARAM_PREMIUM double,
                             -- param_plan_id in INTEGER,
                             in PARAM_COMPANY_CODE varchar(4000),
                             in PARAM_PRODUCT_CODE varchar(4000),
                             in PARAM_PLAN_CODE varchar(4000),
                             in PARAM_EFFECTIVE_DATE datetime,
                             in PARAM_DURATION double, -- float
                             in PARAM_TRANS_AMOUNT double, -- flaot
                             in PARAM_CHANNEL varchar(4000),
                             in PARAM_CREATED_BY varchar(4000),
                             in PARAM_CREATED_IP varchar(4000),
                             out PARAM_RET_CODE varchar(4000),
                             out PARAM_RET_DESC varchar(4000))
sp_lbl:begin

   declare PARAM_EXPIRY DATETIME;
   declare COMP_ID DOUBLE;
   declare PRODUCT_ID DOUBLE;
   -- p_id NUMBER;
   declare PLAN_ID DOUBLE;
   declare PLAN_DURATION double;
   declare PLAN_FEE double;
   declare PLAN_PREMIUM double;
   declare PLAN_TYPE VARCHAR(50);
   declare TRANSACTION_AMOUNT double;
   declare PREVIOUSLYPURCHASEDCOUNT DOUBLE;
   -- param_newtid VARCHAR2(50 BYTE);

  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN
  begin
    rollback;
    set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
    set  PARAM_RET_DESC = 'INVALIDINPUT';
    -- set PARAM_RET_DESC = CONCAT(IFNULL(SQLERRM, '') , IFNULL(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE, ''));
  end;
 -- END;

   set PARAM_RET_CODE = '2';
   -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('i am here!');
   -- param_tid:='495';

  -- Input validations

  -- Company Code validation
  IF PARAM_COMPANY_CODE IS NULL OR PARAM_COMPANY_CODE = '' THEN
    sp_lbl1:loop
    set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
    set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Company Code is required';
    set PARAM_TID = '';
    Leave sp_lbl1;
    end loop sp_lbl1;
  ELSE
      select('Company Code is valid');
      -- Check company code existence in the database
      BEGIN
            DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN
            set COMP_ID = NULL;
            END;
        SELECT ID INTO COMP_ID FROM INSURANCE_COMPANY WHERE CODE = PARAM_COMPANY_CODE AND STATUS = 'Active';
                 END;

      -- Check if company is registered
      IF (COMP_ID IS NULL) THEN
      sp_lbl2:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Company Code is not registered/active with the system';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
          Leave sp_lbl2;
          end loop sp_lbl2;
      END IF;

  END IF;

  -- Product Code validation
  IF PARAM_PRODUCT_CODE IS NULL OR PARAM_PRODUCT_CODE = '' THEN
    sp_lbl3:loop
    set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
    set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Product Code is required';
    set PARAM_TID = '';
    Leave sp_lbl3;
    end loop sp_lbl3;
  ELSE
      select(CONCAT('Product Code is valid' , IFNULL(COMP_ID, '') , IFNULL(PARAM_PRODUCT_CODE, '')));
      -- Check prodcut code existence in the database
      BEGIN
            DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN
            BEGIN
              set PRODUCT_ID = NULL;
              select('Exception Product Id');
            END;
            END;
            DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN
            BEGIN
              set PRODUCT_ID = NULL;
              select(CONCAT('Exception Product Id' , IFNULL(SQLERRM, '') , IFNULL(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE, '')));
            END;
            END;
      -- product_id := 0;
        -- SELECT p.INSURANCE_PRODUCT_ID INTO product_id FROM INSURANCE_PRODUCTS p WHERE ( p.STATUS = 'Active' AND p.COMPANY_ID = comp_id AND p.product_code = param_product_code); -- AND p.STATUS = 'Active' 
         SELECT INSURANCE_PRODUCT_ID INTO PRODUCT_ID  FROM INSURANCE_PRODUCTS WHERE COMPANY_ID=COMP_ID AND PRODUCT_CODE = PARAM_PRODUCT_CODE AND STATUS = 'Active' ;
         select(CONCAT('Product Id : ' , IFNULL(PRODUCT_ID, '')));
       -- product_id := 43;
                 END;



      -- Check if product is registered
      IF (PRODUCT_ID IS NULL) THEN
          sp_lbl4:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Product Code is not registered/active with the Company code in the system';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
          Leave sp_lbl4;
          end loop sp_lbl4;
      END IF;

  END IF;

   -- Plan Code validation
  IF PARAM_PLAN_CODE IS NULL OR PARAM_PLAN_CODE = '' THEN
    sp_lbl5:loop
    set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
    set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Plan Code is required';
    set PARAM_TID = '';
    Leave sp_lbl5;
    end loop sp_lbl5;
  ELSE
      select('Plan Code is valid');
      -- Check prodcut code existence in the database
      BEGIN
            DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN
            set PLAN_ID = NULL;
            END;
        SELECT INSURANCE_PLAN_ID, DURATION INTO PLAN_ID, PLAN_DURATION FROM INSURANCE_PLANS WHERE INSURANCE_PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT_ID AND PLAN_CODE = PARAM_PLAN_CODE AND STATUS = 'Active';
                 END;

      -- Check if plan is registered
      IF (PLAN_ID IS NULL) THEN
          sp_lbl6:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Plan Code is not registered/active with the Product in the system';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
          Leave sp_lbl6;
          end loop sp_lbl6;
      END IF;

  END IF;

   -- Plan Duration Validation       
  IF PARAM_DURATION IS NULL THEN
    sp_lbl6:loop
    set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
    set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Duration is required';
    set PARAM_TID = '';
    Leave sp_lbl6;
    end loop sp_lbl6;
  ELSE
      select('Plan Duration is provided');

      -- Check if duraiton provided is same defined in database
      IF (PLAN_DURATION IS NULL) THEN
          sp_lbl7:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Plan Duration is not defined in the system';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
          Leave sp_lbl7;
          end loop sp_lbl7;
      ELSE

          IF (PLAN_DURATION != PARAM_DURATION) THEN
          sp_lbl8:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Plan Duration is not the same that is defined in the system';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
         -- Leave sp_lbl; 
          leave sp_lbl8;
         end loop sp_lbl8;
          END IF;

      END IF;

  END IF;

   -- Plan Fee / Premium, transactionAmount validation
  IF PARAM_FEE IS NULL THEN
    sp_lbl9:loop
    set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
    set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Plan Fee is required';
    set PARAM_TID = '';
    Leave sp_lbl9;
    end loop sp_lbl9;
    END IF;

  -- Plan Fee / Premium, transactionAmount validation
  IF PARAM_PREMIUM IS NULL THEN
    sp_lbl10:loop
    set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
    set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Plan Premium is required';
    set PARAM_TID = '';
    Leave sp_lbl10;
    end loop sp_lbl10;
    END IF;

  IF PARAM_PREMIUM IS NOT NULL AND PARAM_FEE IS NOT NULL THEN
      select('Plan Fee/Premium is valid');
      -- Check plan fee/premium existence in the database
      BEGIN
            DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN
          sp_lbl11:loop
          set PLAN_FEE = NULL;
            set PLAN_PREMIUM = NULL;
            set PLAN_TYPE = NULL;
            leave sp_lbl11;
            end loop sp_lbl11;
            END;
        SELECT FEE, PREMIUM,FEETYPE INTO PLAN_FEE, PLAN_PREMIUM,PLAN_TYPE FROM PLAN_PRICING WHERE INSURANCE_PLAN_ID = PLAN_ID AND END_TIME IS NULL;
                 END;

      -- Check if plan is registered
      IF (PLAN_FEE IS NULL) THEN
          sp_lbl12:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Plan Fee is not defined in the system';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
          Leave sp_lbl12;
          end loop sp_lbl12;

      END IF;

       -- Check if plan is registered
      IF (PLAN_PREMIUM IS NULL) THEN
          sp_lbl13:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Plan Premium is not defined in the system';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
          Leave sp_lbl13;
          end loop sp_lbl13;

      END IF;

      -- Check if plan is registered
      IF (PLAN_TYPE IS NULL) THEN
          sp_lbl14:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Plan Fee type is not defined in the system';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
          Leave sp_lbl14;
          end loop sp_lbl14;

      END IF;

       -- Check if plan premium is registered
      IF (PLAN_PREMIUM != PARAM_PREMIUM) THEN
          sp_lbl15:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Plan Premium is not the same which is defined in the system';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
          Leave sp_lbl15;
          end loop sp_lbl15;

      END IF;

       -- Check if plan fee is registered
      IF (PLAN_FEE != PARAM_FEE) THEN
          sp_lbl16:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Plan Fee is not the same which is defined in the system';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
          Leave sp_lbl16;
          end loop sp_lbl16;

      END IF;

      -- Check if trnsaction amount is sum of fee and premium
      IF PLAN_TYPE = 'Percentage Amount' THEN
          -- Plan fee is percentage of premium
          set PLAN_FEE = (PLAN_FEE/100) * PLAN_PREMIUM;
      END IF; 

      IF ((PLAN_PREMIUM + PLAN_FEE) != PARAM_TRANS_AMOUNT) THEN
          sp_lbl17:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'Sum of Fee and Premium is not equal to transaction amount provided.';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
          Leave sp_lbl17;
          end loop sp_lbl17;

      END IF;


  END IF; -- outer if condition for param_fee

   -- Check if CNIC has already subscribed this plan
  SELECT COUNT(*) into PREVIOUSLYPURCHASEDCOUNT
  FROM PURCHASED_INSURANCE
  WHERE BENEFICIARY_MSISDN=PARAM_BENEFICIARY_MSISDN AND INSURANCE_PLAN_ID=PLAN_ID AND EXPIRY_DATE>NOW() AND STATUS!='Refunded' AND STATUS!='Unpaid';
  select(CONCAT('Previously Purchased Count ' , IFNULL(PREVIOUSLYPURCHASEDCOUNT, '')));
  IF (PREVIOUSLYPURCHASEDCOUNT > 0) THEN
          sp_lbl18:loop
          set PARAM_RET_CODE = '1';
          set PARAM_RET_DESC = 'The plan has already been subscribed by the beneficiary MSISDN';
          set PARAM_TID = '';
          Leave sp_lbl18;
          end loop sp_lbl18;
  END IF;

   SELECT SEQ_TRANSACTION.nextval INTO PARAM_TID FROM DUAL;
   -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PARAM_RET_DESC = ' || PARAM_RET_DESC);
   -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PARAM_RET_DESC = ' || param_tid);
   SELECT (PARAM_EFFECTIVE_DATE+PARAM_DURATION) INTO PARAM_EXPIRY FROM DUAL;
   INSERT INTO PURCHASED_INSURANCE (TID,FEE,EFFECTIVE_DATE,EXPIRY_DATE,PREMIUM,BENEFICIARY_CNIC,
                                     INITIATOR_MSISDN,INSURANCE_PLAN_ID,BENEFICIARY_MSISDN,INITIATOR_CNIC,CHANNEL, CREATED_BY,CREATED_IP,CREATED_DATETIME,STATUS,TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) 


   VALUES(PARAM_TID,PARAM_FEE,PARAM_EFFECTIVE_DATE,PARAM_EXPIRY,PARAM_PREMIUM,PARAM_BEN_CNIC,
          PARAM_INITIATOR_MSISDN,PLAN_ID,PARAM_BENEFICIARY_MSISDN,PARAM_INITIATOR_CNIC,PARAM_CHANNEL,PARAM_CREATED_BY, PARAM_CREATED_IP,SYSDATE(),'Unpaid',PARAM_TRANS_AMOUNT);

   INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_HISTORY (TID,START_TIME,END_TIME,STATUS,TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,CREATED_BY,CREATED_IP,CREATED_DATETIME)
   VALUES(PARAM_TID,PARAM_EFFECTIVE_DATE,NULL,'Unpaid',PARAM_TRANS_AMOUNT,PARAM_CREATED_BY, PARAM_CREATED_IP,SYSDATE()) ;
   COMMIT;

   set PARAM_RET_CODE = '0';

   -- leave sp_lbl;
END;
end
```

I just see no value in the result but if it's working then it will return 01 with invalid input in exception case and 00 with transaction id in working case

Comment: We don't often get asked to debug 337 lines of code and I'm not saying its impossible to do so without sample data. a description of what it's supposed, sample call statements etc but it would certainly help.

Comment: I tried debugging it whereas it starts with sp_lbl:begin and directly goes to end without executing the internal logic.

Answer (score 0):

Didnt try running it but by just looking at it I can see that there are 2 variables which are storing what is happening in your stored proc.

```
out PARAM_RET_CODE varchar(4000)
out PARAM_RET_DESC varchar(4000)
```

These 2 variables are the actual output of your stored proc.

Whichever may be the condition, but by printing these 2 variables will give you some insights into what is that condition because of which this stored proc is not returning anything. Print them at the end of the stored proc, you will get your answer.